# How to access folders in "Android/data/" using Uri in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

My problem is that I don't have access to the folders in "Android/data/" but I do have access to "Android/data/" Folder by requesting a Uri from the user to confirm it.

this is the code and no matter what I try it always save's the file to "Android/data/" not "Android/data/com.tencent.ig/"

```
public void copy(File src, Uri dst) throws IOException {

    Uri treeUri = getPersistedUriPermissions().getUri();
    Uri subDir = DocumentsContract.buildDocumentUriUsingTree(treeUri,DocumentsContract.getTreeDocumentId(treeUri)+"/com.tencent.ig/");
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,subDir.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    DocumentFile file = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(this,subDir);


    try (InputStream in = new FileInputStream(src)) {
        try (OutputStream out = getContentResolver().openOutputStream(file.createFile("","Active.sav").getUri(),"w")){
            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
            int len;
            while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0){
                out.write(buf,0,len);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You do not have access to data from other apps on external storage on Android 11+.

Comment: I know but I bypassed that using Open Document Tree and requesting Allow Access to all files permission

Comment: Let me explain to you what I'm stuck on, I Have a Uri of a folder and I can Access it but I can't Access the folders inside that @CommonsWare

Comment: "requesting Allow Access to all files permission" -- if you mean that `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission, I do not know if that affects your use of the Storage Access Framework. It may only affect your use of the filesystem directly.

Comment: True, but if you target android sdk 29 and request permission to "android/data/" using OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE in that case you can access and manage all files within that directory

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.